# AJAX compatibilty

Tags: html, php, css, ajax, web-applications

In 2015 Google stopped supporting their AJAX for Adsense program, So I've researched and developed tons of AJAX content. I understand the flaws so I'm striving for backwards compatibility.

```
loadPage('https://www.example.com/home');
function loadPage(){
  customRequest('/php/homepage.php', {one:'var1', two:'var2' }).promise().done(function(data,status,err){     
    $(getElementById('home')).html(data.html);
  });
}
function customRequest(u,d) {
     var promise = $.ajax({ type: 'POST', dataType: 'JSON', data: d, url: u })
     .done(function (responseData, status, xhr) { console.log(responseData); })
     .fail(function (xhr, status, err) { console.log(xhr); });
     return promise;
}
```

Relying on AJAX, my web-app never reloads. I have a function that is built for loading pages into the proper container, much like a modern-app with touch-based input such as SnapChat.

The problem manifests with the 'Fetch as Google' tool, as it does not scan the dynamic content. By changing the DirectoryIndex .html to DirectoryIndex .php in the .htaccess I'll be able to get rid of the first line

```
loadPage('https://www.example.com/home');
```

and handle the initial load with the php file. Is this a really a viable solution or would I still not be able to load the ads in the dynamic content. There's not really any official answer, just several unanswered questions.

Comment: Back in the old days we would never rely on anything JavaScript (ajax), but anymore it's just as essential as HTML and CSS. It's not going away.

Comment: What does AJAX have to do with AdSense, Google's platform to show ads on your site?   Can you share some references?

Comment: Hash bang crawling has been deprecated by Google because Googlebot now crawls JavaScript and AJAX better than it used to.     The "fetch as Google" tool does usually do all AJAX as long as it happens early enough.  I'm not sure exactly what you are talking about here.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it really make sense to rely on AJAX in conjunction with a server-side language like PHP to serve content?

It really depends what you are trying to do. If you plan to make a page of a bunch of short stories, then plain-old HTML will work just fine. Heck, you could even get away without using CSS for stories, but then again, if you want the text somewhat prettier and/or fancier, thats where CSS comes in.

If your site involves submitting something to the server to get a small response back (for example, clicking a submit button on a quiz only to find out if your answer is right or wrong), then ajax will do just fine since then the user doesn't leave the page and a message will appear. As an alternative (especially if Google does cut AJAX scanning for good), you can go super-old-fashioned by creating a simple HTML form and when a user submits something (such as the quiz answer), a separate page loads (via server script aka php file) that tells the user whether he is right or wrong.

But before assuming Google can't handle ajax, you might want to try making all javascript internal to the page (meaning don't use this syntax in your HTML: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/external.js">`). That way when Google scans the page, it won't have to try to load external resources that it may not have permission to access (depending on your server settings).

Comment: I am using AJAX to receive json php responses containing server-rendered html to load pages dynamically into my single page application which loads content into its respective tab depending on the parameters in the pathname. Thus, my function loadPage(window.location.pathname) { if(...) }. The AJAX makes it a problem including ads into the dynamic html. I've had some success with ChitikaAds by inserting the script tags on .html().promise().done(function(){ chitikaAds(); }). What is the best way to load ads into a single page application's dynamic pages, or am I closer than I think?